# Replace rectangular nodes with images and make word captions legible

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

I would like to replace rectangles with images in the MWE below, replacing second data with an image that depicts data, e.g.

I have tried (as in the MWE with the first rectangle) but it's still not working perfectly. The words in the rectangle may appear below the image.

Similarly, I want the words in the rectangle to be legible – every time I download this diagram as pdf and use it in a different `LaTeX` document, the words in the diagram are blurry. I am wondering if there is any way to make the diagram very legible and readable in an article?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=25mm, >=latex',
        block/.style = {draw, rectangle, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=17mm,align=center,fill=green!20!yellow!40!, line width=0.5pt},
        rblock/.style = {draw, rectangle, rounded corners=0.5em},
        tblock/.style = {draw, trapezium, minimum height=10mm, 
            trapezium left angle=75, trapezium right angle=105, align=center},
        ]

        \node [block]                      (start)      {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}\\Function\\ $k(\cdot)$};
        \node [block, right=of start]    (combined)   {First. Data + \\ Second. Data};
        \node [block, above=of combined]     (ref)  {Second Data};
        \node [block, right=of combined]     (detecting) {Training \\ Data};
        
        \node [block, right=of detecting]     (Train) {Train Set};
        \node [block, above =of Train]  (validation)     {Validation};

        \node [block, right=of Train]  (final)     {Function \\ (Re)training};
        \node [block, above = of final]  (checker)     { Check   cycle};



        % Paths with text
        \path[draw,->,line width=0.9pt] (start)      edge node[midway, above,shorten <=0.1mm] {\parbox{1.5cm}{Generate first data \\  samples}} (combined)
                      
                       (ref)   edge node[midway, right] { } (combined)
                       
                       (combined)    edge node[midway, above] {\parbox{1.5cm}{reshuffle  \\  data}} (detecting)
                       
                       (detecting)  edge node[midway, below] { \parbox{1.5cm}{split training \\  data} } (Train)

                        (checker)  edge node[midway, above] {} (final)
                        (final)  edge node[midway, above] {} (checker)

                        (validation)  edge node[midway, above] {} (checker)

                        (Train)  edge node[midway, above] {} (final);

                       
                       % (Train)  edge node[midway, above] {} (final);
                

                   \draw[->,line width=0.9pt] (final.south) -- ++(0,-1.5cm) -- ++(-18.2cm,0) node[midway, below] {\parbox{7.5cm}{After every $(3k)$-th training epoch, $k \in \mathbb{N}$}} |- (start.south);

                
            \draw[->,line width=0.9pt] ([xshift=10mm]detecting.east) |- ($(validation.west)!0.0!(validation.west)$);
      
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you including the PDF with `\includegraphics{}`? Why don't you just compile the diagram in your LaTeX document?  What do you mean by captions? There aren't any `\caption`s? What's the problem in including more images exactly? What does 'still not working perfectly' mean?

Comment: @cfr thank you for the response! By caption I meant words in the rectangle.  Yes I am including PDF with `\includegraphics`. The problem with the way I included the image is that the rectangle still shows up, I want the outline of the rectangle to be erased, and the words to appear at the bottom. Perhaps, the outline of the rectangle won't be visible but it will house the image and the words. I could have compiled directly but I am not sure if compiling it directly might affect the format of the article itself.

Comment: Delete the options you don't want in the definition of `block` e.g. `draw` and `fill=<colour>` or whatever. Or keep `draw` if you want that bit and just delete `fill`. If you want some nodes to be filled and some not, make a second definition without those options e.g. `image block` or whatever and use that.

Comment: @cfr Thanks. I will try out the suggestions.

Comment: @cfr any suggestion on how to add word to the image - such that the words are correctly placed. Thanks

Comment: Please update your code, e.g. by appending it to the end of your question. Please include a screenshot of what that code creates. Less guessing we have to make usually speeds up the whole process. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, but I'm still not sure what exactly you want to change. I don't see any words in a triangle, for example, and where do you want the words to appear? They seem to be below the image already. Is that the problem or what you want?

Comment: @cfr thank you for the update. Apologies, I wasn't aware I wrote "triangle" instead of a rectangle. The rectangles are as depicted in the attached image with some words inside them. I want to replace the rectangles with images and position them correctly, then move the words in each rectangle below the image.

Comment: But what's the problem? You already seem to have one case where you've inserted an image with words below it. What's the problem with the result for that one? I'm not understanding how what you want differs from what you've got.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for the feedback. I am simply trying to see if there is a better way to do it. The rectangle should have no outline, perhaps -the rectangle could be floating above the words directly. If this makes sense.

Comment: So, as I said before, delete `draw` and `fill` from the definition and that is what you'll get. Zarko's done it for you below and fixed the arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As already mentioned @cfr in her comment, what is your problem?
- It seems, that in suggestions below are mostly off-topic ...

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                ext.paths.ortho,    % defined in the tikz-ext package                
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 25mm, 
  start chain = A going right,
   arr/.style = {-Latex, semithick},
 block/.style = {minimum height=12mm, font=\small, 
                 text width=21mm, align=center, inner sep=1pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, text width=21mm, align=center, 
                            font=\footnotesize}
                        ]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=16mm}
% nodes
    \begin{scope}[nodes={block, on chain=A, join = by arr}]
\node   {\includegraphics{example-image-a}\\
         Function\\ $k(\cdot)$};
\node   {\includegraphics{example-image-b}\\
         First. Data + \\ Second. Data};
\node   {\includegraphics{example-image-c}\\
         Training \\ Data};
\node   {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\\
         Train\\ Set};
\node   {\includegraphics{example-image}\\
         Function \\ (Re)training};
    \end{scope}
\node [block, draw, above=of A-2]  (ref)        {Second Data};
\node [block, draw, above=of A-4]  (val)        {Validation};
\node [block, draw, right=of val]  (checker)    {Check cycle};
% Paths with text
\path   (A-1) to ["Generate first data samples"]    (A-2)
        (A-2) to ["reshuffle\\ data"]                 (A-3)
        (A-3) to ["split training data" ']          (A-4);
\draw[arr]  (ref) edge  (A-2)
            (val) edge  (checker)
            (A-5) edge  (checker)
            ($(A-3)!0.5!(A-4)$) |- (val);
\draw[->]   (A-5) r-du  (A-1) node[midway, below, font=\footnotesize]
                                {After every $(3k)$-th training epoch, $k \in \mathbb{N}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Download  the`tikz.ext`  here [CTAN:tikz-ext](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext?lang=en). Then upload `tikzlibraryext.paths.ortho.code.tex` from the downloaded folder to the project folder accordingly.

Comment: +1 For divination.